# Any software that could convert the format of pseudopotential files?

Tags: density-functional-theory, pseudopotentials, siesta

I am using SIESTA 3.2, which seems to only support the .psf pseudopotential format, is there any tools that allow me to convert the pseudopotential files into another format? Or when generating the pseudopotential, could I assign another format?

Comment: You ask about pseudopotential generation, what program are you using for that? You also ask for a pseudopotential file format converter, what is the format of your current output?

Btw, SIESTA 3.2 was released over 9 years ago, are you using such an old version for any particular reason?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6473/7, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/how-to-convert-unified-pseudopotential-format-upf-into-ultrasoft-pseudopotenti